# Adding React.Js to my Asp.net MVC core , is this possible/compatible?

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core-mvc

I am building ASP.NET Core MVC web application, and I am using these technologies:-

1. Entity Framework
2. SQL Server
3. HTML, JavaScript, JQuery & Bootstrap.

But i want to improve my web application front-end by utilizing `React.JS`.. But my question is if this i possible? and if so how i can do so?

Thanks

Comment: https://reactjs.net/tutorials/aspnetcore.html

Comment: @deechris27 thanks for the link , other than this is there a complete documentation about using react.js inside asp.net mvc core?

Comment: Are you looking for a tutorial? Not something that fits here.

Comment: There is a whole tutorial about it in:

https://reactjs.net/tutorials/aspnetcore.html

The only thing you should take into consideration is that you should use webpack for the bundling process

Answer (score 3):

You could create a new project using the React template, and then use that as a reference to help upgrade your existing project. ASP.NET MVC is always so particular about it's configuration and where files should be put, so I've always found it helpful to work with an example. something something monkey see monkey do.

See here how for to create said template: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/react?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

And if CLI isn't your favorite, if have a recent version of Visual Studio IDE or Rider IDE you can create the a new project with the react.js template/option selected.